# Android Studio - Log.i does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

Below is code

```
String messageToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.USER_INFO_PREFERENCE,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String userEmail = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.USER_EMAIL,"");
if (!userEmail.equals("")) {
    Log.i(TAG,userEmail);
} else {
    Log.i(TAG,"Nao ha info");
}

if (messageToken!=null && !userEmail.equals("")) {
    DatabaseReference tokenReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child(Constants.FIREBASE_PATH_USER_TOKEN).child(Constants.encodeEmail(userEmail));
    tokenReference.child("token").setValue(messageToken);
    Log.i(InboxActivity.class.getSimpleName(),messageToken);
}
```

I have no idea why any of the `Log.i` is not printing in the log.

Comment: check your import files

Comment: Only `Log.i` doesn't or the others (`Log.d` , `Log.w` ...) too?  Have you selected `No filter` in logcat option?

Comment: None of the Log works, Log.d, Log.w and all the others. Yes, no Filter is selected and the log is printing three lines:

Comment: 03-22 15:03:22.371 1760-3015/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.casaaberta.beastchat/.activities.InboxActivity} from uid 2000 on display 0
03-22 15:03:23.754 1760-1779/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed org.casaaberta.beastchat/.activities.InboxActivity,wp,ca,1368
03-22 15:03:23.754 1760-1779/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed org.casaaberta.beastchat/.activities.InboxActivity: +1s368ms

Comment: So I know the activity is been called, but no Log is been printed!

Comment: I got this problem solved! Matheus Brandino, from Alura.com.br, just pointed me that I had a wrongly overriden the onCreate method (its not showing here because I had my original post edited). So the solution was to delete the second argument from onCreate.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's because of your build type , logs are not displayed in release mode

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem solved! Matheus Brandino, from Alura.com.br, just pointed me that I had a wrongly overriden the onCreate method (its not showing here because I had my original post edited). So the solution was to delete the second argument from onCreate.

I had:

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {`

Now:

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try going to developer settings on your android phone, Find "Monitoring" Option and then "Enable OpenGL Traces" and then select LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

Run -> Edit Configurations -> Android app -> app -> Miscellaneous -> Tick all the check boxes -> Apply

Hope this help.